# Need to remove zero's from html table

Tags: php

```
function getannualSalarystmtpdf($tableData){
      $compdetails = array ();
      $stmt ="SELECT  c.company_email,c.company_name,c.company_logo,c.company_build_name,c.company_street,c.company_area,c.company_city,
            c.company_pin_code FROM company_details c WHERE c.company_id = '" . $_SESSION ['company_id'] . "' AND c.info_flag='A'";
    $result = mysqli_query ( $this->conn,$stmt );
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) {
        array_push ( $compdetails, $row );
    }

    $html = '<div class="reportTable"><table id="annualTable" style="width:100%;" ><thead><tr>';

    foreach($tableData[2] as $k=>$v) {
            if($v!='-'  )
            $html .= '<th style="text-align:center;">' .$k. '</th>';

    }


        $html .= '<th style="text-align:center;">Total</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

        for ($i = 0, $len = count($tableData); $i < $len; ++$i) {
            $header="";
            if($i % 2 == 0){
                $html .= '<tr class="alt">';
            }else{
                $html .= '<tr>';
            }

           $total=0;

            foreach($tableData[$i] as $k1=>$v1) {
                if($k1=='SALARYHEADS' ){
                    if(explode("_",$v1)[1]=='A' ){
                        $html .= '<td style="text-align:left;">ALLOWANCES</td>';

                    }else if(explode("_", $v1)[1]=='D') {
                        $html .= '<td style="text-align:left;">DEDUCTION</td>';

                    }else if(explode("_", $v1)[1]=='Gross'){
                        $html .= '<td style="font-weight:bold;text-align: right;">'.explode("_", $v1)[1].'</td>';
                        // header= '<tr><td colspan="13">Deduction</td></tr>';

                    }else if(explode("_", $v1)[1]=='Net Salary'){
                        $html .= '<td style="font-weight: bold;text-align: right;">'.explode("_", $v1)[1].'</td>';
                    }else if(explode("_", $v1)[1]=='TotalDedu'){
                        $html .= '<td style="font-weight: bold;text-align: right;">'.explode("_", $v1)[1].'</td>';

                    } else{
                        $html .= '<td style="padding-left: 15%;">'.explode("_", $v1)[1].'</td>' .$header;

                    }

                }

                else if($v1!='-'  ){


                    $html .= '<td style="text-align:right;">' . inr_format($v1) . '</td>';

                    $total+=floatval($v1);

                }


            }

                $html .= "<td style='text-align:right;'>" . inr_format($total) .'</td></tr>';
                echo $html;
                die();

        }



        $html .= '</tbody></table></div>';

        include_once (dirname ( dirname ( dirname ( __FILE__ ) ) ) . "/js/mpdf/mpdf.php");
        $mpdf = new mPDF ( 'en-GB-x', 'L', '', '', 10, 10, 10, 10, 6, 3 ); // if remove note isset into 20
        $styleSheet = file_get_contents ( dirname ( dirname ( __DIR__ ) ) . "/css/reportTable.css" );
        $header1 .= '<table> <tr>
      <th style="width:20% "><img src=../' . $compdetails [0] ['company_logo'] . ' style="width:15%"></th>
      <td style="font-weight: bold;font-size:15px;text-align:left; ">' . ucwords ( $compdetails [0] ['company_name'] ) . '<br>' . ucwords ( $compdetails [0] ['company_build_name'] ) . ',' . ucwords ( $compdetails [0] ['company_street'] ) . ',' . ucwords ( $compdetails [0] ['company_area'] ) . ',<br>' . ucwords ( $compdetails [0] ['company_city'] ) . ',' . $compdetails [0] ['company_pin_code'] . '</td></tr></table>';
        $mpdf->WriteHTML ( $styleSheet, 1 );
        $mpdf->setAutoTopMargin='stretch';// Writing style to pdf
        $mpdf->setHeader ( $header1 );
        $mpdf->setHTMLFooter ( $footer );
        $mpdf->WriteHTML ( $html, 2 );
        $mpdf->Output ( 'provisional_Statement_' . $name . '.pdf', D );
        exit ();
```

}

I have also attached an image.. I want to remove the zero's from the allowances and deduction of april and may month.. Only display zero in total.. What small logic should i write for that? Table gets generated dynamically.. 
[image: Remove the zero's from allowances and deduction header of april and may month]

Comment: Which part of code is setting values for Total field?

Comment: Use an `if()` statement to display a blank instead of the value if it's zero.

Comment: Yoo need something like this in your code
`if($valueOfTotalField != 0){
      $html .= 'your_html';
}`